# Matrices Problem

Tags: matrices

I am doing the Cambridge O/L 2012 M/J P1 4024/12 Paper, Question number 12 (b).

$$m = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}, \quad n = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} $$

Given that 
$$sm+3n = \begin{pmatrix}12 \\ t \end{pmatrix}$$

Calculate $s$ and $t$.

Please explain me the method. I don't just want the answer. $m, n$ are matrices with $1$ column and $2$ rows but idk how to write it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that two vectors are equal if and only if all their components are the same. So
$$s \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}+ 3\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ t \end{pmatrix} \iff \begin{pmatrix} 3s-3 \\ -2s+12 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ t \end{pmatrix}$$
This leads to the equation system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 3s-3 &=& 12 \\ -2s+12&=&t \end{array}\right. \iff \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 3s &=& 15 \\ -2s+12&=&t \end{array}\right. \iff \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} s &=& 5 \\ t&=&-2\cdot 5+12=2 \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Thanks! Got P1 Exam tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You have $M=\left(\begin{matrix}3 \\ -2\end{matrix}\right)$ and  $N=\left(\begin{matrix}-1 \\ 4\end{matrix}\right).$

The product of a number and a matrix gives a new matrix with entries the product of the number and the entries of the original matrix. Thus

$sM=s\left(\begin{matrix}3 \\ -2\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}3s \\ -2s\end{matrix}\right)$ and  $3N=3\left(\begin{matrix}-1 \\ 4\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-3 \\ 12\end{matrix}\right).$

Now, to add two matrices you have to add their entries in the same position, that is,

$sM+3N=\left(\begin{matrix}3s \\ -2s\end{matrix}\right)+\left(\begin{matrix}-3 \\ 12\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}3s-3 \\ -2s+12\end{matrix}\right).$

Finally two matrices are equal if any of the entries in the same position are equal, that is,

$\left(\begin{matrix}3s-3 \\ -2s+12\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}12 \\ t\end{matrix}\right)$ means $3s-3=12$ and $-2s+12=t.$ Now solve the equations and you will get the values of $s,t.$